# Strategy for computing PMI from counts: dataframes or matrices

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I need to compute PMI scores for co-occurrences of bio-entities e.g. `Gene A - Gene B`, or `Gene C - Disease A`. Co-occurrences have been extracted from [Pubtator](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/CBBresearch/Lu/Demo/PubTator/curator_identifier.cgi?page=1&Species_display=1&Chemical_display=1&Gene_display=1&Disease_display=1&Mutation_display=1&pmid=15803373). I use Python 3.

For a set of documents, I have extracted the individual counts `freq(x)` and `freq(y)` of all entities by co-occurrence category e.g. `Gene-Gene` or `Gene-Disease`, and I have the co-occurrence counts of entity pairs `freq(x,y)`. All counts are stored in a `Dict`.

What would be the best approach for computing Pointwise Mutual Information (PMI) scores from the raw counts:

- Create two data frames (one for individual counts and one for co-occurrence counts)
- Create two matrices? (same as above)
- another approach?

Consider that one set of data has 3 columns: `entity, category, count` and the other set has 4 columns: `entity_a, category, entity_b, count` where category represents the co-occurrence category. I need the category for the individual entity counts because if I were to use their overall total counts it would distort the results for a given co-occurrence type.

I have attempted the data frame approach but can't figure out a way how to create a new PMI column that computes the result using two different data frames (DFs) hence I thought maybe a matrix approach may work better? If so, why?

Examples of the data when transformed into DFs:

df1.head():

`ent        rel count
177   5197  Gene_Gene     2
176  56744  Gene_Gene     2
175  12766  Gene_Gene     2
174   3091  Gene_Gene     2
173   3162  Gene_Gene     2`

df2.head():

`ent_a        rel  ent_b count
247   5197  Gene_Gene  56744     1
246  12766  Gene_Gene   5197     1
245  12766  Gene_Gene  56744     1
244   3091  Gene_Gene   3162     1
243   3091  Gene_Gene  54583     1`

The PMI formula :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy I found to work for me consists of using both DataFrames (DFs) and numpy arrays.

In a first step, DFs were useful for looking up and populating `df2` with the respective individual counts of the co-occurring entities. Then, in a second step, numpy arrays were used to efficiently compute the (approximated) `PMI` score for each of the co-occurrences.

**Step 1: Lookup Individual Counts**

- first split the co-occurring entities and add each to a new column e.g.:

  `df_ab['ent_a'] = df_ab.ent_ab.apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])`
- then call a lookup function to get the individual counts e.g.:

  `df_ab['ent_a_count'] = df_ab.ent_a.apply(get_ent, args=(df_a, 'ent_a', ))`

  where the lookup function looks like this:

  `def get_ent(ent_df_ab, df_a, colname_df_ab):
      row_df_a = df_a[df_a[colname_df_ab] == ent_df_ab]
      i = row_df_a.iloc[0]['count']
      return i`

`df2` now looks like this

````
```
        ent_ab  count_ab       type  ent_a  ent_b  ent_a_count  ent_b_count
0   5197-56744         2  Gene_Gene   5197  56744            2            2
1   12766-5197         1  Gene_Gene  12766   5197            2            1
2  12766-56744         1  Gene_Gene  12766  56744            2            2
3    3091-3162         4  Gene_Gene   3091   3162            6            1
4   3091-54583         2  Gene_Gene   3091  54583            6            1
```
````

**Step 2: Vectorized PMI Calculation**

- numpy array-based function for computing scores

  `def compute_pmi(df):
      count_ab = np.array(df[['count_ab']])
      ent_a_count = np.array(df[['ent_a_count']])
      ent_b_count = np.array(df[['ent_b_count']])
      pmi = np.round(count_ab / (ent_a_count * ent_b_count), 3)
      df['pmi'] = pmi
      return df`